# How to check whether each file that selected is video or image in flutter project and how to preview the list of selected file?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the code that I write but I can choose both multi video and multi images but I don't have no idea to preview the file before upload .I think I need to check the file type first and if the file that selected is video , I want to show it with videoController, if the file that selected is image,
I want to show it with Image.file .But I don't have no idea about that please help me.
Here is the code

```
> import 'dart:io';
> import 'dart:math';
> 
> import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
> import 'package:facebook_app/screens/home_screen_layout.dart';
> import 'package:facebook_app/services/image_storage.dart';
> import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
> import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
> import 'package:gallery_picker/gallery_picker.dart';
> import 'package:get/get.dart';
> import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
> import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
> import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
> import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
> import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
> import '../models/post_moel.dart';
> import '../models/user_model.dart';
> import '../provider/user_provider.dart';
> import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
> 
> class MultiFileUplaodScreen extends StatefulWidget {
> const MultiFileUplaodScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
> 
>   @override
> _MultiFileUplaodScreenState createState() => _MultiFileUplaodScreenState();
> }
> 
> class _MultiFileUplaodScreenState extends State<MultiFileUplaodScreen> {
> List<File> images = [];
> 
> TextEditingController Controller = TextEditingController();
> bool _isLoading = false;
> VideoPlayerController? _controller;
> bool isVideo = false;
> 
> TextEditingController? _controller = new TextEditingController();
>   @override
> void dispose() {
> super.dispose();
> 
> Controller.dispose();
>   }
> 
> Preview(File files) {
> if (isVideo) {
> VideoPlayerController.file(files);
> else {
> Image.file(files);
>     }
>   }
> 
> void Posttask(
> String uid,
> String profileUrl,
> String username,
> async {
> setState(() {
> _isLoading = true;
>     });
> try {
> String res = await uploadPost(Controller.text, downloadUrls, uid,
> username, profileUrl, DateTime.now());
> if (res == "success") {
> await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
> MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenLayout()));
> setState(() {
> _isLoading = false;
>         });
> 
> showSnackBar("Posted", context);
> else {
> setState(() {
> _isLoading = false;
>         });
> showSnackBar('Posted', context);
>       }
> catch (e) {
> showSnackBar(e.toString(), context);
>     }
>   }
> 
> Future<void> _onImageButtonPressed(
> ImageSource source, {
> required BuildContext context,
> bool isMultiImage = false,
> bool isMedia = false,
> async {
> if (_controller != null) {
> await _controller!.setVolume(0.0);
>   //   }
> if (context.mounted) {
> if (isVideo) {
> final XFile? file = await _picker.pickVideo(
> source: source, maxDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10));
> await _playVideo(file);
>   //     }
>   //   }
>   // }
> Null _onImageShow(XFile medias) {
> onshow(){
> if (isVideo) {
> _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(medias.path));
> else {
> Image.file(File(medias.path));
>   //   }
>   // }
> return  onshow();
>   // }
> 
>   @override
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).refreshUser();
> final User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
> return Scaffold(
> appBar: AppBar(
> title: Text("Upload multiple files"),
> leading: IconButton(
> icon: Icon(
> Icons.arrow_back,
>           ),
> onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
> MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenLayout())),
>         ),
>       ),
> body: Container(
> width: double.infinity,
> child: SingleChildScrollView(
> child: Column(children: [
> SizedBox(
> height: 50,
>             ),
> InkWell(
> onTap: () {
> getMultipImage();
>             //   },
> 
> child: Container(
> width: 200,
> height: 200,
> decoration: BoxDecoration(
> border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
> child: const Center(
> child: Icon(
> Icons.upload_file,
> size: 50,
>             //         ),
>             //       )),
>             // ),
> 
> Row(
> children: [
> CircleAvatar(
> backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user?.photoUrl ?? ""),
>                 ),
> const SizedBox(
> width: 20,
>                 ),
> Text(user?.username ?? '')
>               ],
>             ),
> Container(
> decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
> height: 40,
> padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
> 
> child: TextField(
> cursorColor: Colors.purple,
> maxLines: 10,
> controller: Controller,
> decoration: InputDecoration(
> enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
> borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple)),
> focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
> borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
> hintText: "Description",
> hintStyle: TextStyle(
> color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
>               ),
>             ),
> const SizedBox(
> height: 20,
>             ),
> Container(
> width: Get.width,
> height: 150,
> child: images.length == 0
> Center(
> child: Text("No Images found"),
>                     )
> ListView.builder(
> scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
> itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
> return Container(
> width: 100,
> margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
> height: 100,
> decoration: BoxDecoration(
> border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
> child: Image.file(
> images[i] as File,
> fit: BoxFit.cover,
>                           // ),
> child: Preview(
> images[i]
>                             ),
> ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
>                           //
>                         );
>                       },
> itemCount: images.length,
>                     ),
>             ),
> const SizedBox(
> height: 50,
>             ),
> 
> Row(
> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
> children: [
> Text("Add photos"),
> const SizedBox(
> width: 20,
>                 ),
> Container(
> child: IconButton(
> onPressed: getMultipImage,
> icon: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
> color: Colors.green,
> iconSize: 30,
>                     ),
> decoration: BoxDecoration(
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
> color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 228, 228)))
>               ],
>             ),
> const SizedBox(
> height: 20,
>             ),
> _isLoading
> CircularProgressIndicator(
> color: Colors.blue,
>                   )
> Padding(
> padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
> child: MaterialButton(
> color: Colors.blue,
> minWidth: double.infinity,
> shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
> height: 50,
> onPressed: () async {
> for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
> String url = await uploadFile(images[i]);
> downloadUrls.add(url);
> 
> if (i == images.length - 1) {
> Posttask(
> Controller.text,
> user?.uid ?? '',
> user?.photoUrl ?? '',
>                             // );
> Posttask(user?.uid ?? '', user?.photoUrl ?? '',
> user?.username ?? '');
>                           }
>                         }
>                       },
> child: Text("Upload"),
>                     ),
>                   )
>           ]),
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> 
> List<String> downloadUrls = [];
> 
> final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
> 
> getMultipImage() async {
> final List<XFile> pickedImages = await _picker.pickMultipleMedia();
> 
> if (pickedImages != null) {
> pickedImages.forEach((e) {
> images.add(File(e.path));
>       });
> 
> setState(() {});
>     }
>   }
> 
> Future<String> uploadFile(File files) async {
> final metaData = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg');
> final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
> Reference ref = storageRef
>         .child('pictures/${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg');
> 
> final uploadTask = ref.putFile(files as File);
> 
> final taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
> String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
> return url;
>   }
> 
> storeEntry(List<String> imageUrls, String name) {
> FirebaseFirestore.instance
>   //       .collection('child')
>   //       .add({'image': imageUrls, 'name': user?.username??""}).then((value) {
> Get.snackbar('Success', 'Data is stored successfully');
>   //   });
>   // }
> uploadPost(
> String description,
> List<String> imageUrls,
> String uid,
> String username,
> String profileImage,
> DateTime datePublished,
> async {
> String res = "Some Errors occured";
> 
> try {
> String postId = const Uuid().v1();
> Post post = Post(
> comment: [],
> likes: [],
> datePublished: DateTime.now(),
> description: description,
> postId: postId,
> profileUrl: profileImage,
> uid: uid,
> username: username,
> postMediaFileUrl: imageUrls,
> share: [],
>       );
> FirebaseFirestore.instance
>           .collection('posts')
>           .doc(postId)
>           .set(post.toJson());
> Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
> MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenLayout()));
> res = "success";
> catch (e) {
> res = e.toString();
>     }
> return res;
>   }
> }
>
```